# how to use slug for only certain links in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pretty-urls

I use a slug instead of an ID in my rails app to prettify the url when viewing a post.

Therefore in my articles.rb file I currently use this for all links:

```
 def to_param
    slug
  end
```

This results in a url like: ...articles/this-is-a-test-article

I now want to use the normal id url format only when editing a post, is there a way to modify this to allow me to do that?

i.e. ...articles/7

For reference, in my articles controller I have:

```
def edit
@article = Article.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have something (eg a before_filter) which does something like `@article = Article.find_by_slug(params[:id])` in your controller?

Comment: Yes I do, sorry I'll add that to the question

Comment: You can just add it as a `before_action` for the methods which you need and excepting `edit` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**friendly_id**

You'll be much better using [**`friendly_id`**](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

This works exactly how you need (you have the `slug` column already, and you'll need to do this):

```
#app/models/article.rb
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    friendly_id :slug, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

--

**`.find`**

The reason why `friendly_id` will be good is it has [adapted the `find` method of Rails](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#what-changed-in-version-50) to handle both slugs & id's:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
def [action]
    @article = Article.find params[:id]
end
```

This means you can do this:

```
article_path(@article) #-> can have either id or slug attributes present
```

This will populate the `:id` param with either the `id` or `slug`, depending on which is present, allowing you to call the `find` method in the controller for either.

Comment: Thanks Rich, I think this answered the question best however the best approach for me was to manually define the path and find by id: `def edit_article_path() "/articles/#{@article.id}/edit" end` and `def edit @article = Article.find(params[:id]) end`

Answer (score 0):

So, in the params you're always getting `params[:id]`, and it happens that sometimes this is equal to the slug of the article you want and in other times it's equal to the id.

In the former case you should say

```
@article = Article.find_by_slug(params[:id])
```

In the latter case you should say

```
@article = Article.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

You could manage this with a before_filter, which you don't use in the edit action or something along those lines.

EDIT:

To make a link that uses id instead of params, just be specific in the helper:  if you pass through the object, rails will call to_param on it to generate the value for params[:id].  You don't have to pass through the object:

```
edit_article_path(:id => @article.id)
```

Comment: Cheers Max, only thing is, I want the route/url to have the ID in it when I click on a link to edit and not the slug, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it as `before_action` just for the methods for which you want to `slug` and excepting `edit` method from the `before_action`

something like this

```
before_action :set_article, only: [:show,:update, :destroy]

def edit

@article = Article.find_by_id(params[:id])

end

private
def set_article
@article = Article.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan, I am aware of that already, my problem is that `def to_param slug end` makes all links have the slug and not the id, I need the id in the link when I go to the edit section